# FB-Connect simple script not working

Tags: facebook, fbml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.og/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://facebook/2008/fbml">
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>


<fb:login-button onlogin="update_user_box();"></fb:login-button>

<script>
function update_user_box(){
user_box = document.getElementById("user");
user_box.InnerHtml = "<span>"
+"<fb:profile-pic uid='loggedinuser' facebook-logo=true></fb:profile-pic>"
FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree();
}
FB.init("APP_ID","xd_reciever.htm");

</script>
<div id="user"></div>
```

This is my script. Actually i want to fetch the profile picture of logged in user from facebook connect. But this is not working, I got this script from http://mashable.com/2008/12/11/facebook-connect-blog/ and i can't find what's my error. How to get it correct to work like-what i want?

Comment: That script is just outdated – the `FeatureLoader.js.php` script should not be used any more. Please read the documentation on how to embed and use the _current_ JS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
  // assume we are already logged in
  FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

  function showProfile(response) {

if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
      });
    } 
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(showProfile);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', showProfile); 


  (function() {
          var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
          e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
          document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

Then have two div's for the login button and for storing the profile info.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" autologoutlink="true"></div>
<div id="user"></div>
```